# Auto run an excel macro to format rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have daily excel reports that get created by an external program. I am looking to automate a simple row formatting on these reports. They always have the same number of columns, however, different number of rows.

This is the macro I have in place: (it does the job as expected when run on a single xlsm file, which is not ideal)

```
Sub FormatLeadLists()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Columns("A:F").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.29
Columns("A:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "Table1"
Range("Table1[#All]").Select
End Sub
```

This is the .vbs code that I run from a batch file:

```
Dim args, objExcel

Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "FormatLeadLists"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

This works well on a single file, however, to make this work I have to create my macro in my "All Open workbooks" and have to save my excel as an xlsm file.

That's not ideal if I have these reports overwritten every day as xlsx files.

How can I create a macro in my personal workbook so I don't have to save the report as xlsm and so I can apply the same macro on the other xlsx reports?

I know I should even be able to create a .vbs file that loops through my windows folder and applies the macro on all existing excel files.

Edit:

Code for the loop (from comments):

```
Dim strFileName As String 
Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "C:\myfiles\" 
Dim strFileSpec As String: strFileSpec = strFolder & "*.*" 

strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec) 
Do While Len(strFileName) > 0 
  Debug.FormatLeadLists strFileName 
  strFileName = Dir 
Loop
```

Comment: Please narrow down your question to a single issue, and if there are many, then post them separately. Thanks and regards,

Comment: Are the files you want to format all open, or closed but all in the same folder?

Comment: all closed and in the same folder. I'll be running the batch file with a windows scheduler.

Comment: Have you tried iterating your code over all files within a loop?

Comment: @David, I have the code to loop but haven't tested it yet because I haven't yet figured out how to setup my original script to run the macro, on any  xlsx file, not a specific xlsm one.

This is the code I would use for the loop (courtesy of a someone on http://codevba.com)


    `Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "C:\myfiles\"
    Dim strFileSpec As String: strFileSpec = strFolder & "*.*"
    strFileName = Dir(strFileSpec)
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
      Debug.FormatLeadLists strFileName
      strFileName = Dir
   Loop`

Comment: never mind here... I hired someone on upwork to get it done properly... Thanks